# Is LINQ faster than ADO?

Tags: vb.net, performance, linq, ado.net

I am new to LINQ so to start exploring I created a multithreaded time app to see what is faster LINQ or ADO.  This app counts how long I have at work till it's time to go home.  The timer is set to 1 second, calling the same SP.

Am I missing something?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Time

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    lblADOTime.Text = ADO()
    lblTime.Text = Net()
    lblLinq.Text = tLinq()

End Sub

Private Sub Time_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim tADO As Thread
    Dim tNet As Thread
    Dim tLinq As Thread
    tADO = New Thread(AddressOf Me.ADO)
    tADO.Start()
    tNet = New Thread(AddressOf Me.Net)
    tNet.Start()
    tLinq = New Thread(AddressOf Me.tLinq)
    tLinq.Start()
End Sub
Private Function tLinq() As String
    Dim db As New DataClasses1DataContext
    'db.Connection.Open()

    Dim myDate As String
    myDate = Date.Today + " 17:00:00"
    Return "LINQ: " + db.TimeLeftToday(myDate).ToList().Last.Column1

    'db.Connection.Close()

End Function
Private Function Net() As String
    Dim a As DateTime
    a = Date.Today + " 17:00:00"
    Dim s As String
    s = (a - Now()).ToString
    Return ".NET: " + s 's.Substring(1, 8)

End Function

Private Function ADO() As String
    Try
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = meh

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("TimeLeftToday", conn)

        cmd.CommandText = "TimeLeftToday"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Today", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, "@Today"))
        cmd.Parameters(0).Value = Date.Today + " 17:00:00"
        cmd.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()
        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        sdr.Read()
        If sdr.HasRows Then

            Return "ADO: " + sdr.GetValue(0)

        End If
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)



    End Try

End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I don't think LINQ is meant to be faster, it's just meant to be simpler.

Comment: You're missing a few things: 1) speed isn't usually the only criterion. 2) You're not comparing against "linq", you're comparing against "LINQ to SQL", which is not the only LINQ provider.

Comment: LINQ <> Database.  Linq stands for Language INtegrated Query.  It is a sql like syntax that is added to VB and C# but by no means is it database related as you can use it with arrays or other collections with no database involved.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to SQL uses ADO.NET underneath, so there is no way it could be faster.

You could ask, why people use it, when it has worse performance? Because in some cases the performance isn't that crucial. And you have to admin, that LINQ to SQL is much easier to use! And because of that development process can be done quicker, easier and in more dev-friendly way.

Comment: Hi, in this experiment LINQ outperforms ADO by 3 Milliseconds :)  Don't know about it being easy, took me like 2 hours to figure out how to get it working :(

Comment: Any discrepancy you'd see between linq to sql and straight ado.net calls would likely be due to the generation/caching of resulting queries